# Using cmake with nmake x64

Tags: cmake, 64-bit, nmake

I use cmake to generate a NMake file, everything goes fine.

I use the x64 toolsets (without Visual Studio, only the SDK), so I type nmake, but it generate a x86 build and not a x64 build.

Do you know why ? and how to force nmake to target x64 ?

Thanks

Comment: How do you generate your NMake file with CMake? Please show the command.

Answer (score 12):

Just to share, use the following to force the x64 platform. Use this command prompt command.

```
VsDevCmd.bat -host_arch=amd64 -arch=amd64
```

Both -host_arch and -arch are mandatory !