# Building openSSL for Windows x64

Tags: c, configuration, openssl

Basically this should be quite simple, but for some magic reason result library is `Win32` not `x64`.

During investigation I've found that first step `Configure` is failing:

```
perl Configure VC-WIN64A no-asm enable-static-engine --prefix=x64\Release
```

This prints (full copy paste):

```
Configuring for VC-WIN64A
    no-asm          [option]   OPENSSL_NO_ASM
    no-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 [default]  OPENSSL_NO_EC_NISTP_64_GCC_128 (skip dir)
    no-gmp          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_GMP (skip dir)
    no-jpake        [experimental] OPENSSL_NO_JPAKE (skip dir)
    no-krb5         [krb5-flavor not specified] OPENSSL_NO_KRB5
    no-libunbound   [experimental] OPENSSL_NO_LIBUNBOUND (skip dir)
    no-md2          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_MD2 (skip dir)
    no-rc5          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_RC5 (skip dir)
    no-rfc3779      [default]  OPENSSL_NO_RFC3779 (skip dir)
    no-sctp         [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SCTP (skip dir)
    no-shared       [default]
    no-ssl-trace    [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SSL_TRACE (skip dir)
    no-ssl2         [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SSL2 (skip dir)
    no-store        [experimental] OPENSSL_NO_STORE (skip dir)
    no-unit-test    [default]  OPENSSL_NO_UNIT_TEST (skip dir)
    no-weak-ssl-ciphers [default]  OPENSSL_NO_WEAK_SSL_CIPHERS (skip dir)
    no-zlib         [default]
    no-zlib-dynamic [default]
IsMK1MF=1
CC            =cl
CFLAG         =-DOPENSSL_THREADS  -DDSO_WIN32 -W3 -Gs0 -Gy -nologo -DOPENSSL_SYSNAME_WIN32 -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -DL_ENDIAN -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
EX_LIBS       =
CPUID_OBJ     =mem_clr.o
BN_ASM        =bn_asm.o
EC_ASM        =
DES_ENC       =des_enc.o fcrypt_b.o
AES_ENC       =aes_core.o aes_cbc.o
BF_ENC        =bf_enc.o
CAST_ENC      =c_enc.o
RC4_ENC       =rc4_enc.o rc4_skey.o
RC5_ENC       =rc5_enc.o
MD5_OBJ_ASM   =
SHA1_OBJ_ASM  =
RMD160_OBJ_ASM=
CMLL_ENC      =camellia.o cmll_misc.o cmll_cbc.o
MODES_OBJ     =
ENGINES_OBJ   =
PROCESSOR     =
RANLIB        =true
ARFLAGS       =
PERL          =perl
SIXTY_FOUR_BIT mode
DES_INT used
RC4_CHUNK is unsigned long long

Configured for VC-WIN64A.
```

Note that `CFLAG` contains options for `Win32`. This is quite unusual and I have no idea what is wrong and how do I approach this problem.

My build script more or less looks like this (initially it was building for `Win32` I do modification to support `x64`):

```
REM setup some variables
call commonSetup.cmd

set PREFIX=x64\Release
set PLATFORM=VC-WIN64A
set MS_CONF=do_win64a
set EXT=

pushd %THIRD_PARTY_DIR_BASE%\openssl

echo PREFIX=%PREFIX% PLATFORM=%PLATFORM% MS_CONF=%MS_CONF% EXT=%EXT%

perl Configure %PLATFORM% no-asm enable-static-engine --prefix=%PREFIX%

call ms\%MS_CONF%

perl -i.bak -pe "s/([-\/])Zi /\1Z7 /g" ms/nt.mak

mkdir inc32\openssl
nmake -f ms\nt.mak

REM jom -f ms\nt.mak AS=ml64 -j %PROCN%
nmake -f ms\nt.mak install

rmdir /s/q inc32
rmdir /s/q out32%EXT%
rmdir /s/q tmp32%EXT%
```

Any help will be appreciated.

OpenSSL version:  `1.0.2p` `14 Aug 2018`

I do not have this problem when building other dependencies of my project to `x64` platform.

I've found [this question with exactly same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43656019/1387438), but answers there do not match my problem. My VS tools are configured properly (VS2017). I have to use VS and I have no problems to use it (`nmake` works).

Comment: Do you actually get a 32-bit library if you go forward with the build?  Although I see "WIN32" in the names of some of the defined symbols in the C flags, I don't think any of those control the target architecture for which the library will be built.

Comment: yes. I'm checking what is the outcome with `dumpbin /headers %LIB_TO_CHECK% | find machine`

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks for the help. This given me a hint I can try search problem in other step.

Answer (score 1):

Ok finally I've got the solution.
I've found in [other SO ansear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48662062/1387438).

Basicly `nmake` must be reconfigured to build for `x64` (openSSL Configure was not the problem) using this:

```
VsDevCmd.bat -host_arch=amd64 -arch=amd64
```

After earlier attempts `nmake -f ms\nt.mak clean` had to be invoked so above could take effect.

Comment: it really works, my final scripts for build openssl 1.1

```bat
PATH C:\strawberry-perl-5.32.1.1-64bit-portable\perl\bin;%PATH%
PATH C:\NASM;%PATH%
set custom_dir=C:\opssl
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"  -host_arch=amd64 -arch=amd64
perl Configure VC-WIN64A no-asm enable-static-engine --prefix=%custom_dir%
nmake
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for Marek R, it really works, my final scripts for build openssl 1.1, summarize as below

```
PATH C:\strawberry-perl-5.32.1.1-64bit-portable\perl\bin;%PATH%
PATH C:\NASM;%PATH%
set custom_dir=C:\opssl
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"  -host_arch=amd64 -arch=amd64
perl Configure VC-WIN64A no-asm enable-static-engine --prefix=%custom_dir%
nmake
```

prerequest:

- openssl1.1 source
- strawberry perl
- NASM
- VS (verified with VS2019 community version)

Comment: If you're going to be using this for development (ie running the script over and over again), perhaps you should add `setlocal` at the top.  Otherwise you'll be adding strawberry and nasm to an ever-growing path.