# How to enable the x86 version of Developer PowerShell for VS 2022

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2022

In earlier versions of Visual Studio it used to have both x86 and x64 versions for the Developer PowerShell.
In the 2022 version, it only has the x64 version. How can I enable the x86 version?
Thank you.

I tried to run "Windows PowerShell (x86)" and then run vcvars32.bat on it. Although it says Environment initialized for: 'x86' but for example does not recognize nmake. While nmake is recognized in the x64 Developer PowerShell.

Comment: Do you have the x86 SDKs/build-tools installed (under VS Installer > Individual Components)?

Comment: The Microsoft documentation says to use "one of following" then doesn't list anything.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/starting-windows-powershell?view=powershell-7.4#starting-the-32-bit-version-of-windows-powershell

Comment: _"In earlier versions of Visual Studio it used to have both x86 and x64 versions for the Developer PowerShell."_ - I have VS2019 installed right now, and I don't have a x86/32-bit _and_ x64 Developer PowerShell start-menu shortcut. I think you're having a false-memory. It's only the non-PowerShell _Developer Command Prompt_ that has x86 and x64 start-menu shortcuts.

Comment: See following : https://4sysops.com/wiki/differences-between-powershell-versions/#rtoc-4

Comment: @jdweng _Developer PowerShell_ is a separate start-menu shortcut. The OP isn't asking about the non-VS Windows PowerShell shortcuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In earlier versions of Visual Studio it used to have both x86 and x64 versions for the Developer PowerShell.

I think you have a false-memory there, because I have VS2019 installed and there's only 1 VS2019 PowerShell shortcut, and it isn't labelled for x86 nor x64.

> In the 2022 version, it only has the x64 version.

The VS2022 PowerShell start-menu shortcut isn't labelled x64 (or x86) either:

| VS2019 | VS2022 |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |
| `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noe -c "&{Import-Module """C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll"""; Enter-VsDevShell 7d25e381}"` | `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noe -c "&{Import-Module """C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll"""; Enter-VsDevShell 3537ba3e}"` |

> I tried to run "Windows PowerShell (x86)" and then run vcvars32.bat on it. Although it says Environment initialized for: 'x86' but for example does not recognize nmake. While nmake is recognized in the x64 Developer PowerShell.

`vcvars32.bat` is for `cmd.exe`, not PowerShell.

Re: `nmake`, that's best run under `cmd.exe` instead of PowerShell anyway; so the separate x86 and x64 (and ARM) start-menu shortcuts for those are just what you need.

FWIW, you *can* still use the x64 version of `nmake` to target 32-bit x86, [just set the right environment-variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48661598/using-cmake-with-nmake-x64);

Comment: You've set me on the right track. What I needed was x86 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022

Comment: Nice. So it looks like the only "Developer"-named shortcut for PowerShell is 32-bit, despite not saying so in the name. Why is `nmake` best run under `cmd.exe`?

Comment: @mklement0 I wrote that because trying to use "normal" command-line programs in PowerShell is just _awkward_ (e.g. having to use `./`, `&`, `Invoke-Item`, etc) all the time, and how it's just _slower all-round_ (it still takes 2-3 seconds to start-up on my machine). [You can't even run a `.bat` or `.cmd` file in PowerShell without feeling like _they're trying to punish you_](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2021/08/run-batch-file-from-powershell.html).

Comment: @Dai, that article provides poor guidance in my estimation. It doesn't mention the core difference that you've identified: the need to invoke a batch file located _in the current directory_ by a _path_ not just by name, by security-minded design; e.g. ``.\some.cmd``. Tab-completion eases the pain of having to type ``.\`` manually. The other gotcha is that a _quoted_ batch-file path requires invocation via `&`, the call operator (`& '.\some file.cmd'`). Apart from that, there's _basically_ no difference in invocation syntax, though you need to be aware of different metachars. and quoting rules.

Comment: However, there are edge cases that require workarounds: space-less arguments that contain `cmd.exe` metachars. such as `&` break the invocation, _embedded_ `"` chars. require manual escaping,
and arguments that the ultimate target executable must see with _partial_ quoting, notably `msiexec`, aren't preserved as such.
I certainly wish those were addressed, but they weren't: see [GitHub issue #15143](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15143).
As for the startup cost: point taken, but that's the price you pay for loading a vastly superior shell (its quirks notwithstanding).

Comment: @mklement0 Whereas `bash` loads instantly - and is an even more superior shell 

Comment: `bash` is definitely superior to `cmd.exe` and loads quickly. I don't think we need to discuss this further, but let me state that in my estimation PowerShell is also vastly superior to Bash, due to its rich scripting language, rich type support, and virtually unlimited access to .NET. One thing it isn't: fast. Also, historically it has neglected decent integration with calls to external programs, which is only slowly improving (e.g., v7.4.0 finally brought raw-byte redirections). If one's main use for a shell is calling external CLIs, then indeed PowerShell isn't the best choice.

Comment: @mklement0 Developer PowerShell becomes x64 in an update of VS 2022. But yes it used to be x86. That caused all the confusion in my case. I was trying to build a 32 bit version of libcurl. But you have to run it in a 32 bit build environment to build it correctly. Otherwise it confuses the build-script and builds a 64 bit version but says it is 32 bit.